# WinForms press a button automatically using a external tool

Tags: .net, winforms

I am in charge of several servers and I need to run multiple desktop applications on each of them (aprox. 50 per server). These apps are started at startup using a scheduled task.

The problem is that I need to start each application manually (I.e. pressing a button) every time I restart the servers.

So far I tried to start the applications with a PowerShell script using:

```
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($proc.Id)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("~")
```

But this approach is not a reliable method, since  **SendKeys** send the key stroke to the active window as per Microsoft documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008.aspx)

So I'd like to know if there is a reliable way to start these applications automatically using a external application/tool.

P.S.

I do not have access to the code.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, but `AutoIt` might be a good place to start.

An alternative method would involve using the Win32 API (`EnumWindows` and its ilk) to grab the handle (hWnd) for each button you want to click and send the appropriate window messages (SendMessage, WM_MOUSEDOWN, WM_MOUSEUP come to mind).

Answer (score 2):

I used a tool called [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) pretty reliably in the past.

If you can figure out the keystrokes to press (Tabs, Alt, etc.) in order to put the button in focus, it should work for you.

Comment: I would strongly second this. I once used this approach to automate some scientific equipment that could only be controlled via a GUI app on an ancient desktop. This worked where all else had failed. It's not pretty but it's scriptable and will get the job done. Just be sure to add a few delays if you're clicking a lot of buttons.